# C++ lua bridge problems with function pointers

Tags: c++, lua, function-pointers

I am trying to create a simple c++ wraper over *lua_CFunction* and it is defined like :

```
// header
typedef int (*lua_CFunction) (lua_State* lua);
...
lua_CFunction wrap (std::function <int (Game* game)> function);
// implementation
lua_CFunction ScriptingInterface::wrap (std::function <int (Game* game)> function) 
{
    return [this, function] (lua_State* unused) -> int {
        int n_args = function (this->game);
        return n_args;
    };
}
void ScriptingInterface::registerFunction (std::string name, std::function <int (Game* game)> function) 
{
    lua_register (lua, name.c_str (), wrap (function));
}
```

The idea is to create public functions like this :

```
int setTitle (Game* interface) 
{
    const char* title = lua_tostring (interface->getScripts ()->getLuaState (), 1);

    SDL_WM_SetCaption (title, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

And share them with lua like :

`scripts->registerFunction ("setTitle", setTitle);`

*scripts* is an instance of **ScriptingInterface**

The problem occurs when trying to compile the game.

```
./scripting/scripting_interface.cc: In member function ‘int (* ScriptingInterface::wrap(std::function<int(Game*)>))(lua_State*)’:
./scripting/scripting_interface.cc:40:2: error: cannot convert ‘ScriptingInterface::wrap(std::function<int(Game*)>)::<lambda(lua_State*)>’ to ‘int (*)(lua_State*)’ in return
./scripting/scripting_interface.cc:41:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in here, because AFAIK the code should compile without any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
lua_CFunction ScriptingInterface::wrap(std::function<int(Game*)> function) 
{
    return [this, function] (lua_State* unused) -> int {
        int n_args = function (this->game);
        return n_args;
    };
}
```

You are trying to return a lambda where a function pointer is expected, but a *capturing* lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer - and your lambda is capturing both `this` and `function`. Per Paragraph 5.1.2/6 of the C++11 Standard:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture** has a public non-virtual non-explicit const
>   conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s
>   function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function
>   that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

Unfortunately, unless you can return an `std::function<int(lua_State*)>`, you will have to change your design.

Comment: `./scripting/scripting_interface.cc:45:2: error: cannot convert ‘std::function<int(lua_State*)>’ to ‘int (*)(lua_State*)’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void lua_pushcclosure(lua_State*, int (*)(lua_State*), int)’` That obviously didn't work. Maybe I can solve my problem with `mem_fn`. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Aleksandar: That won't be convertible to a function pointer either unfortunately. `std::bind` will also not help you. It seems Lua will just accept function pointers, so I don't see much room for flexibility. You may have to figure out something that uses a `static` function.

Comment: @Aleksandar: Glad I could help a bit, good luck with your project